# google oAuth - how to delete cookie after login from google oAuth

Tags: oauth-2.0

i have develop an application with google oAuth, this is working fine.

I am able to login and access my website.

My question is, when i do sign out (logoff) from my application, i remove all sessions, but the authenticated cookie (made by google oAuth) is not deleted.

so, rightnow when i do logoff, and login using google oAuth, it is directly login in to system,
without asking email and password to authenticate on google account.

Anyone having idea what i need to do in order to delete that cookie and force the user to login again using google oAuth after logout once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My implementation, gives me idea about these. if you do logout from your application from which you use Gmail to login, you will not be able to logout to other application running on browser like FB.

I mean....

If I login in  my application using Gmail account. and in the same browser if i login to Gmail (mail) account.

IN this case, when i do Logout from my application, and refresh Gmail(mail) it is still login because Gmail works on Token base.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe can logout using this link.

```
https://accounts.google.com/Logout?continue=http://google.com
```

Comment: It gives me `the page you requested is invalid` error when I'm specifying my own server URL in continue section. Any idea why? like I'm specifying https://accounts.google.com/Logout?continue=https://testapp-id.appspot.com/auth